# How to support .Net FW 4.6.1 in InstallShield 2015 professional edition

Tags: installshield

This is not a question but a post.
To support .Net FW 4.6.1 in Install Shield 2015 professional edition, follow the steps mentioned in 
https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?220164-prq-for-Microsoft-NET-Framework-4-6-1-Full

but pls verify registry path of .Net 4.6.1 in *.prq file.

If this does not work in one go and if you have received similar error as below:

> "An error occurred streaming
>   'Microsoft.net\4.6\Full\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' into
>   setup.exe"

then run InstallShield 2015 professional in admin mode and try.

After doing bit of analysis I found the actual issue.

Problems in the *.prq files:

> 1. I tried to install it in Win7(32 & 64)systems, Set up did not prompt for missing 4.6.1. Then I checked the *.prq file again and
>      found out It does not included entry for supporting Win7 and other OS
>      32 bit. So better copy supported OS info from .Net 4.5 full.prq file.
>      Please check missing OS info from other *.prq file and add to your prq file.
> 2. Somehow using this 4.6.1.prq file IS 2015 was downloading wrong offline installer for 4.6.1. So, I had to download offline installer
>      from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49982
>      and copied it to "C:\Program Files
>      (x86)\InstallShield\2015\SetupPrerequisites\Microsoft .net\4.6\Full"
>      folder

Now its prompts in Win7 32& 64 bit and works correctly

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Full.prq file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SetupPrereq>
  <conditions>
    <condition Type="2" Comparison="2" Path="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" FileName="Release" ReturnValue="394254"/>
  </conditions>
 <operatingsystemconditions>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1" ProductType="2|3">    </operatingsystemcondition>
<operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="1" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
<operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4" ProductType="2|3"></operatingsystemcondition>
<operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="1" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
<operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="2" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
<operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="2" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
<operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="3" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
<operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="3" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
<operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="10" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
<operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="10" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
  </operatingsystemconditions>
  <files>
    <file LocalFile=".\Microsoft.net\4.6\Full\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" URL="https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/4/1/E4173890-A24A-4936-9FC9-AF930FE3FA40/NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" CheckSum="864056903748706E251FEC9F5D887EF9" FileSize="0,67681000"/>
  </files>
  <execute file="NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" cmdline="/showrmui /passive " cmdlinesilent="/q /norestart" returncodetoreboot="1641,3010" requiresmsiengine="1"/>
  <properties Id="{D88AEC72-8F72-4075-B2EA-1FF6363E0E51}" Description="This prerequisite installs the .NET Framework 4.6.1 full standalone package."/>
  <behavior Reboot="2"/>
</SetupPrereq>
```

Comment: First of all you do not have to check for the Vista (OS version 6.0), the second, remove "Bits" and that condition will check for both 32 and 64.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the text that can be used to create your own .prq file for the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Full Prerequisite.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SetupPrereq>
  <conditions>
    <condition Type="2" Comparison="2" Path="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" FileName="Release" ReturnValue="394254"/>
  </conditions>
  <operatingsystemconditions>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="1" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" ServicePackMajorMin="1"/>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="2" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion=""/>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="3" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion=""/>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="10" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion=""/>
  </operatingsystemconditions>
  <files>
    <file LocalFile=".\Microsoft.net\4.6\Full\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" URL="https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/4/1/E4173890-A24A-4936-9FC9-AF930FE3FA40/NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" CheckSum="864056903748706E251FEC9F5D887EF9" FileSize="0,67681000"/>
  </files>
  <execute file="NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" cmdline="/showrmui /passive " cmdlinesilent="/q /norestart" returncodetoreboot="1641,3010" requiresmsiengine="1"/>
  <properties Id="{D88AEC72-8F72-4075-B2EA-1FF6363E0E51}" Description="This prerequisite installs the .NET Framework 4.6.1 full standalone package."/>
  <behavior Reboot="2"/>
</SetupPrereq>
```

Notes:
The Conditions are set for 64bit only, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10
The download location is good as of 18 January 2016. No telling how long it will last.

Help:
For those new to making a Prerequisite .prq file:

- On your desktop create a new text file.
- Rename this file “Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Full.prq”
- Copy the above text to this new file.
- Move this new file to folder C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2015\SetupPrerequisites
- Open any InstallShield project
- Go to the Installation Designer tab > Application Data > Redistributables. The list should now contain the new entry “Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Full”
  To the right of the list it will say “Needs to be downloaded”
- Right-click on the item Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Full.prq and select  " Download Selected Item…"

This downloads the 66 MB file to C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2015\SetupPrerequisites\Microsoft.net\4.6\Full\
You should be good.

To edit any of the Conditions:
Right-click on the item Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Full.prq and select Edit Prerequisite